# sql query xml values returning NULL

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I'm not experienced with the `xml` structure and need a start-point to how I can retrieve the values from `xml` structure below.

I fetch the `xml` from a `webservice` using a `stored-procedure` and store to a table "StockInfoXML"
Field in table holding the `xml` is **XML_Url** of type `xml`.

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
  <StockQuotes>
    <Stock>
      <Symbol>ENGI.PA</Symbol>
      <Last>13.53</Last>
      <Date>5/23/2017</Date>
      <Time>12:37pm</Time>
      <Change>+0.06</Change>
      <Open>13.45</Open>
      <High>13.59</High>
      <Low>13.40</Low>
      <Volume>1524437</Volume>
      <MktCap>32.95B</MktCap>
      <PreviousClose>13.47</PreviousClose>
      <PercentageChange>+0.48%</PercentageChange>
      <AnnRange>10.77 - 15.20</AnnRange>
      <Earns>-0.23</Earns>
      <P-E>N/A</P-E>
      <Name>ENGIE</Name>
    </Stock>
  </StockQuotes>
</string>
```

I've tried a couple of things but keep returning `null` or nothing.

```
declare @X XML;

SELECT
@X = XML_Url
FROM dbo.StockExchangeInfoXML

SELECT 
x.s.value('(StockQuotes/Stock/Symbol)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS [Symbol]
FROM @X.nodes('./StockQuotes/Stock') AS x(s);
```

Anyone who can get me started?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your xml includes a namespace `xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"`, which is the *default namespace*. You must either declare it or use a wildcard for the prefix.

With XML there are some best practices:

- Be as specific as possible
- Only forward navigation
- **Important** If the creation of the XML is under your control change the date and time format to ISO8601. Your formats are culture specific and can easily lead to conversion errors on different systems. Best was a combined value like `<DateAndTime>2017-05-23T12:37:00</DateAndTime>`

For your issue there are several approaches:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
  <StockQuotes>
    <Stock>
      <Symbol>ENGI.PA</Symbol>
      <Last>13.53</Last>
      <Date>5/23/2017</Date>
      <Time>12:37pm</Time>
      <!--more elements -->
    </Stock>
  </StockQuotes>
</string>';
```

--Best approach: `XMLNAMESPACES` to declare the *default namespace*

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/')
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/string/StockQuotes/Stock/Symbol/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

--Implicit namespace declaration:

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'declare namespace ns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
                   (/ns:string/ns:StockQuotes/ns:Stock/ns:Symbol/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

--Not recommended in most cases, but good for *lazy people* :-D

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(//*:Symbol)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

--If you want to read more values of the same level, you can use `.nodes` to set the current node to `...<Stock>`.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/')
SELECT st.value('(Symbol/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
      ,st.value('(Last/text())[1]',N'decimal(10,4)')
      --more nodes 
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/string/StockQuotes/Stock') AS A(st);
```

Comment: Thx Shnugo for quick and spot on solution! This did it for me :)

Comment: Yes, I'm a newbie here so I expected your comment! Struggled a bit to find how to do accept, but think I managed. Thx again.

Answer (score 2):

You must set namespace for xml before get value

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
  <StockQuotes>
    <Stock>
      <Symbol>ENGI.PA</Symbol>
      <Last>13.53</Last>
      <Date>5/23/2017</Date>
      <Time>12:37pm</Time>
      <Change>+0.06</Change>
      <Open>13.45</Open>
      <High>13.59</High>
      <Low>13.40</Low>
      <Volume>1524437</Volume>
      <MktCap>32.95B</MktCap>
      <PreviousClose>13.47</PreviousClose>
      <PercentageChange>+0.48%</PercentageChange>
      <AnnRange>10.77 - 15.20</AnnRange>
      <Earns>-0.23</Earns>
      <P-E>N/A</P-E>
      <Name>ENGIE</Name>
    </Stock>
  </StockQuotes>
</string>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.webserviceX.NET/' as ns)
SELECT 
x.s.value('(./ns:Symbol)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS [Symbol]
FROM @xml.nodes('/ns:string/ns:StockQuotes/ns:Stock') AS x(s);
```

Returns

```
Symbol
--------
ENGI.PA
```

Comment: This is a correct answer (+1 from my side), but can be improved a bit: As `xmlns="Something"` defines the *default namespace*, there's no need for a namespace prefix at all... Furhermore I would not recommend `.nodes()` just to read one single value... Quite some overhead...