# SQL XML Query returning Blank value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to setup a query to read an XML variable and it appears to be returning an empty table.

The XML I am using:

```
<collection>
  <object parentid="57ae88af-425e-448f-a0a3-b83738fe51b1" parenttype="Object">
    <fields>
      <field name="ID">
        <value>57</value>
      </field>
    </fields>
  </object>
  <object parentid="57ae88af-425e-448f-a0a3-b83738fe51b1" parenttype="Object">
    <fields>
      <field name="ID">
        <value>58</value>
      </field>
    </fields>
  </object>
</collection>
```

The values I want to read are between these tags: `<value>58</value>`

I used this answer to get the code working in the first place:
[sql query xml values returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156552/sql-query-xml-values-returning-null)

After trying various combinations from other answers with "Cross Apply" etc

The code I have got working so far:

```
DECLARE @T1 AS XML

  SET @T1 = (
  SELECT
  (CONVERT(XML,p.Selected_Roles))

 FROM [ReportDB1].[dbo].[Job_Roles] AS P
 WHERE p.ID ='27' )

 SELECT 
 t.x.value('value[1]', 'int') AS test
 FROM @T1.nodes('/collection/objects/fields/field') t(x)
```

I would expect an output of every value in the values tag to be listed in column test. What actually happens is I get the column test but no rows.

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Your code seems to be perfectly okay, but there is a typo: `FROM @T1.nodes('/collection/objects/fields/field')`: `objects` does not have the `s` in the sample XML...

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo, have corrected and it is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

**IF** this is for **SQL Server** - then you can use something like this (if you want *only* the values inside the `<value>..</value>` tags):

```
SELECT
    xc.value('data(.)', 'int')
FROM
    @T1.nodes('/collection/object/fields/field[@name="ID"]/value') AS XT(XC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo resolved issue, credit to Shnugo: correct code should be:

```
DECLARE @T1 AS XML

  SET @T1 = (
  SELECT
  (CONVERT(XML,p.Selected_Roles))

 FROM [ReportDB1].[dbo].[Job_Roles] AS P
 WHERE p.ID ='27' )

 SELECT 
 t.x.value('value[1]', 'int') AS test
 FROM @T1.nodes('/collection/objects/fields/field') t(x)
```